# I've setup logic app in VS code but function expression editor is not working, it's greyed out

Tags: azure, azure-logic-app-standard

I've setup logic app in VS code with all pre requisites libraries but when i tried to dynamic expression i.e function to variable value its throwing me an error and not able to add the function to variable value. I've attached the screen shot for the same.
VS code version: 1.78(user specific)

I've cleared the cache of editor but issue persists.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H471.png)

Answer (score 0):

*I am able to add the variable value from Dynamic content in the following way and I am using vs code version 1.82.2.*

Initially I have created a stateful workflow using logic app extension and then right clicked on workflow.json to open the designer view

[image]

I have used both the options and able to add variable values.

[image]

Click on Add

[image]

[image]

I am able to get the output as below

[image]

[image]